# Canadian tourist visa

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, tourist-visas, applications

I am an Indian citizen with permanent residence from Norway. Having a full time job with sufficient funds. My husband and I are planning to apply for Canadian visa. He has just temporary residence . My husband has a real uncle who gonna sponsor us but my question is during filling of application form should also have to say yes to question ( do you have anyone relative in Canada) it’s not mine uncle who gonna sponsor.  So I can’t prove my relationship. What should I do in this situation as a spouse? Please clear my doubts

Comment: I don't see that question on the visa application?

Answer (score 4):

Your husband's relative is also your relative.  Unless they explicitly ask for proof of the relationship, you don't need to provide it.

Also, a "sponsor" is not mandatory, nor is one even helpful in cases such as yours where you can afford to travel to Canada on your own.  Your visa application would be just as strong if you were visiting a friend who was no relation at all, or indeed if you were just traveling to Canada for some sightseeing on your own.  In fact, it might even be stronger without a relative in Canada, because the officer would be less likely to suspect that you would want to stay in Canada.

Comment: Gonna have to agree with this 100%, the application is better and more likely to get accepted if you were just applying for tourism without mentioning any relatives

Comment: @Huangism but if the application explicitly asks about relatives in Canada, it would be deception not to mention them. This is especially true of any relatives whom the traveler intends to meet during the visit.

Comment: It sure is deception which is why I did not say anyone should do that. It's ultimately up to the person applying. Although any good consultant will probably tell you not to put relatives down even though you are meeting them lol Again I am not suggesting anyone to do that, just stating some facts

Comment: @Huangism a consultant who advises lying on a visa application is not likely to be a "good" consultant.  I recall at least one question posted here by someone who was refused for deception in the UK for failing to mention a relative outside the immediate family, who if I remember correctly was the applicants aunt or uncle.

Comment: Well that depends on how you define good, lots of consultant do it because they know it has a higher success rate. It's hard to say what's good or not, on the one hand you will get in easier to see who you want to see but lie on your application, on the other if you don't lie you might not get in at all and not see who you want to see

Comment: So I should not mentioned about his a uncle in my application? What about my husband? If we apply at same time it would be considered as a lie if he shows in his application & 2nd question what does it mean by showing a proof of relationship? How can my husband proof that he is his real aunvle.

Comment: @Huangism one also has to weigh the higher success rate against the more severe consequences of failure, which can result in a long ban or even, depending on the country, an indefinite one.

Comment: @Rajvir if the application explicitly asks about relatives in Canada, definitely mention the uncle.  If it asks for your accommodation plans, and you're going to be staying with the uncle, definitely mention him.  "What about my husband?": the facts in your husband's application should match the facts in yours.  If the application explicitly asks for proof of relationship then your husband should submit three birth certificates: his own, his uncles, and of the person who is both his parent and his uncle's sibling. You should submit those plus your marriage certificate.

Comment: @Rajvir but the [temporary resident visa application](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5256-applying-visitor-visa-temporary-resident-visa.html#5256E4) does not seem to ask about relatives in Canada.  What visa are you applying for?

Comment: @phoog yep, it's ultimately the applicant's decision, knowing what I know about the process I wouldn't blame the applicant or Canada if things don't go well no matter which route is taken

Comment: Yesterday when I logged myself in to fill application online than  i have to answer some question that I mentioned above & afterward I came across to that page where I have to uploaded my all documents they mentioned clearly about the documents of proof of relationship etc. so my point is if I say yes the question about having a family member in Canada than further I have to say yes to question ( can u proof relationship with that person) & than I must also upload documents for proving of relationship. In this column I can’t upload any document as my husband. So m very confuse regarding this.

Comment: It is a temporary residence permit we r applying for

Comment: @Rajvir to prove your relationship to your husband's uncle, you need four documents: your marriage certificate, your husband's birth certificate, your husband's parent's birth certificate, and your husband's uncle's birth certificate.

Comment: Thanks for advice. So I have to upload all these documents to prove. His uncle sent us an invitation letter in which he mentioned about his income & stated that he gonna be responsible for our all expenses during our visit although we have also sufficient funds to prove that. But he have not sent us documents like lease etc. is it enough or we do need all those document?

Comment: @Rajvir it is very difficult for me to know whether you need those documents without knowing the exact wording of the questions to which you are responding on the application.  Your uncle's saying that he is responsible for your expenses is probably a bad idea, because it could make you look desperate, unless he is actually paying for the trip.  If he is not paying, then the point of his letter is just to establish that you aren't lying about visiting him, and that he is giving you a place to stay (if you are in fact staying at his place).

Comment: Ok. I got it. Can I ask u one more think. When it comes to showing travel history. Since I am holding permanent residence permit so I can freely travel to all schengen Countries. I had visited many land like France, Portugal & Nederland but I don’t have any stamp on my passport. How can I prove this. I have ticket. Can I attach them as a proof ?